# I cloned Ubuntu 20.04 from a Ubuntu 20.04 KVM Server, after reinstall on another Ubuntu 20.04 KVM Server, startx does not work

Tags: xorg

I cloned a VM Ubuntu 20.04 from a Ubuntu 20.04 KVM Server. I then reinstalled it on another Ubuntu 20.04 KVM Server. The origanl Server is newer then the second Server. I had no problems creating the VM Server from the clone. I just can't get "startx" to work. I have tried "apt purge gdm3" and "apt install gdm3". I even reinstalled the "ubuntu-desktop". ".Xauthority" is correct. "Xorg -configure" didn't work either. I tried booting with "nomodeset". No matter what user, it even doesn't work with "root"
lspci - 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Red Hat, Inc. QXL paravirtual graphic card (rev 04)
This is the same on both origanl and cloned VM Servers.

lspci - 08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1) (rev 05) - older Server

lspci- 05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1) (rev 42) - newer Server

After I start "startx"

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.9
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-140-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux 1099-VMUbuntu-2004 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.8.0-59-generic root=UUID=5e2188b4-e53f-4637-befa-279a3ce00e48 ro quiet splash vconsole.keymap=de-latin1-nodeadkeys video=640x480 vt.handoff=6
Build Date: 08 April 2021  12:29:22PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/auto/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Apr  4 11:34:05 2023
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
resizing primary to 1024x768
primary is 0x56473ac6ba90
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I compared /home/USER/.local/share/xorg logs. They were the same until the end.

```
[  2336.538] (II) event4  - spice vdagent tablet: device removed
[  2336.584] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
[  2336.584] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
[  2336.584] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
[  2336.584] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
[  2336.584] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
[  2336.584] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
[  2336.584] (II) config/udev: removing device spice vdagent tablet
[  2336.596] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2336.596] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[  2336.607] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to release device: Device not taken
[  2341.129] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2341.129] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[  2341.156] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2341.156] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[  2341.176] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2341.176] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[  2341.216] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2341.216] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[  2341.250] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file
```

Comment: Nobody has an idea? I have tried everything. The only thing that works, is a complete new install. But that can not be the answer.

Comment: Does anybody need more information?